# Trying to pull XML file from URL, and then pulling in attributes contained inside a tag

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I'm trying to pull data from a live XML document, hosted on a remote server. I'm trying to do this using PHP.

The layout of the XML file is like this:

```
<carparkData>
<Northwest>
<carpark name="PARNELL" spaces="51"></carpark>
<carpark name="ILAC" spaces=" "></carpark>
<carpark name="JERVIS" spaces="616"></carpark>
<carpark name="ARNOTTS" spaces="170"></carpark>
</Northwest>
<Northeast>
<carpark name="MARLBORO" spaces="185"></carpark>
<carpark name="ABBEY" spaces="97"></carpark>
</Northeast>
<Southwest>
<carpark name="THOMASST" spaces="193"></carpark>
<carpark name="C/CHURCH" spaces="51"></carpark>
</Southwest>
<Southeast>
<carpark name="SETANTA" spaces=" "></carpark>
<carpark name="DAWSON" spaces="113"></carpark>
<carpark name="TRINITY" spaces="178"></carpark>
<carpark name="GREENRCS" spaces="446"></carpark>
<carpark name="DRURY" spaces="562"></carpark>
<carpark name="B/THOMAS" spaces="168"></carpark>
</Southeast>
</carparkData>
```

Using PHP I have tried to firstly pull the data, and then to create a loop to catch the attributes contained inside the `<carpark>` tag:

```
<?php

$data = simplexml_load_file('http://www.dublincity.ie/dublintraffic/cpdata.xml.');

foreach ($data->carpark[0]->attributes() as $a => $b) 
{
        echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
}
```

Comment: try `foreach($data->Northwest->carpark as $b) {` then look at the attributes of $b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of right now you are not iterating through the `carparks`. This might point you in the right direction:

```
$data = simplexml_load_file('http://www.dublincity.ie/dublintraffic/cpdata.xml');

if($sectors = $data->children()){
    foreach($sectors as $sector){
        echo '<h1>'.$sector->getName().'</h1>';
        if($carparks = $sector->children()){
            foreach($carparks as $carpark){
                if($attributes = $carpark->attributes()){
                    foreach($attributes as $key=>$value){
                        echo $key.': '.$value.'<br>';
                    }
                    echo '<hr>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I probably were these "fallen trees" in code which lead to the invention of something called *XPath*.

Answer (score 1):

Use `xpath` to get to the `<carpark>`-nodes directly:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x

$carparks = $xml->xpath("//carpark");

foreach ($carparks as $carpark) 
    echo $carpark['name'] . " has " . $carpark['spaces'] . " spaces.<br />";
```

see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/JUB4Jp

Comment: Hi, thank you guys for your contributions. Both these methods work perfectly when I run the php in my local WAMP server, but when I upload them to my remote webserver, it appears to just hang and not load any of the data Any suggestions?